# MySQL Query to Round Everything to Full Minute Duration Per Instance of Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timestamp, duration

I have a table where each row has a duration field that is represented in seconds.

I am looking to compute the sum for each foreign key where the duration field is rounded up for seconds to minutes.

For example, 3 seconds should be rounded up to 1 minute. 90 seconds should be rounded up to 2 minutes. 121 seconds should be rounded up to 3 minutes...etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select sum(ceil(duration/60)*60)
```

If you just want minutes, remove the `*60`:

```
select sum(ceil(duration/60))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. For example, I got 6000 from this SELECT statement. I need the output to be in terms of minutes. Even if I divide this result of 6000 by 60, it comes out to 100 when in reality the duration should be 5 minutes.